# Why ctrl+c in console kills the background process

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Could you explain why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in my `bash` shell affects the command that was run previously in background with:

```
`./my_script.sh 1` &
```

The command immediately finishes the execution with `130` code:

```
[1]+  Exit 130              `./my_script.sh 1` &
```

The usual behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is to kill foreground process. And what does happen here?

Edit 1: (My thoughts) maybe something related to backticks - here child subshell process starts and it somehow receives <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when the parent process recieve it

Edit 2: I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> stops all background processes that were run from the current shell with the use of backticks.

Comment: Was that the previous command entered into your shell?

Comment: @bgStack Don't understand: it is `./my_script.sh 1` & . Or do you ask about the last command before Ctrl-C?

Comment: Forgot to escape the backticks in the previous comment. Should read as: `\`./my_script.sh 1\` &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the command

```
`./my_script.sh 1` &
```

you are doing a ***command substitution*** (see below).
Practically you are executing a *subshell* (the one for the backticks ``` `` ```) in background (`&`) in which it runs your script (`./my_script.sh 1`).

The **present shell** is waiting the end of the execution of its subshell to run its output as commands.
The **subshell** is waiting the end of your script.
When **you press** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you interrupt this waiting, passing the signal `SIGINT` to the child.

In this moment the current shell tries to run as command the output obtained till now... and it generates the error `130` that means *"Script terminated by Control-C"* <sup>[[2](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html)]</sup>.

---

With the backticks ``` `` ```, as well as with `$()`, in bash you are doing a ***command substitution*** <sup>[[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04)]</sup>:

> Bash performs the expansion by executing COMMAND and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

for example

> ```
> echo `date`   
> Thu Feb 6 10:06:20 CET 2003
> ```

---

Note that if you run in background more of this kind of commands

```
`./myscript 1` &
`./myscript 2` &
`./myscript 3` &
```

it is always the current shell that is waiting for all the childs output. A single <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will end this waiting for all together.

If instead you will wait the end of the script, the current shell will try to execute their output as they will finish.

Comment: Yes, it really executs the output! Thank you for the explanation! And is "passing the signal `SIGINT` to the child" the default behaviour of `bash`? Or only when using command substitution?

Comment: The second you said. BTW do some tests... `sleep 10; echo ok` as script... `&`... ctrl c... enjoy your time!